# JPA / Hibernate - persist enums as table of constants

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

Currently, I'm using the standard way to map enums with Hibernate, e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Job {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected State state;
}

public enum State{
    NEW,OLD;
}
```

Now the requirements changed, and I **have to** create a table `State`, which contains all the valid values of my enum as String constants. Thus `Job` must refer to the `State` table. I don't have to migrate legacy data.

1. What options do I have to map this with JPA / Hibernate?
2. Is it possible, to let Hibernate create the `State` table **with values** ( 1->"new", 2->"old").
   during DDL generation?

Comment: The fact that you do not know how to do it might be seen as a clue of a design flaw. If there is some code associated to each enum value, it must be an enum and should not have a table in database (because of sync problems). If there is no code associated to each enum value, it should be an entity, not an enum. Having it both as a table AND an enum seems weird. Can you tell us more about why you need to achieve this?

Comment: Second hint : do not let Hibernate generate the DDL. (IMHO)

Comment: it does not need to be an enum, but there's existing code using it. It's a general requirement regarding all enums in this existing project.

Comment: I don't see how it is a problem. As long as you continue to save the name of the enum in the Job table, whether the column is a varchar, or a varchar with a foreign key constraint to a State table, is irrelevant to Hibernate. A varchar is a varchar. The only problem you have is to generate the database schema, but that shouldn't be Hibernate's responsibility anyway, IMO. Use FlywayDB, Liquibase, or simple SQL scripts.

Comment: the `Job` table must refer to the PK  of the `State` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in ended up with a solution, which generates the DDL including enum constants and foreign key constraints.

e.g.

```
@Entity
public enum MyEnum{
    @EnumValue
    private String name;
    @Id
    private int id;
}
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @EnumReference
    protected MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

is sufficient with the following `MetadataContributor` (*/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor*):

```
public class EnumConstantsMetadataContributor implements MetadataContributor {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnumConstantsMetadataContributor.class);

    private final static List<String> ENABLED_ON = Arrays.asList("validate", "update", "create", "create-drop");
    private final static Integer DEFAULT_VARCHAR_SIZE = 255;
    private final static Identifier DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME = Identifier.toIdentifier("enum_constant", false);

    @Override
    public void contribute(InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector, IndexView jandexIndex) {
        if (shouldRun(metadataCollector)) {
            addEnumsAsTableConstantsAndFkConstraint(metadataCollector);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldRun(InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector) {
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = metadataCollector.getMetadataBuildingOptions().getServiceRegistry();
        ConfigurationService config = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class);
        String setting = config.getSetting(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, String.class, null);
        return (setting != null || ENABLED_ON.contains(setting));
    }

    private void addEnumsAsTableConstantsAndFkConstraint(InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector) {
        for (PersistentClass persistentClass : metadataCollector.getEntityBindings()) {
            Class<?> plainJavaClass = persistentClass.getMappedClass();
            if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom((plainJavaClass))) {
                createEnumInsertsAndDbColumns(persistentClass, plainJavaClass, metadataCollector);
            }
            tryAddFkConstraint(persistentClass, metadataCollector);
        }
    }

    private void tryAddFkConstraint(PersistentClass persistentClass, InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector) {
        Consumer<Field> createEnumFkConstraintForField = field -> {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            PersistentClass targetPersistentClass = metadataCollector.getEntityBinding(field.getType().getCanonicalName());
            if (targetPersistentClass == null) {
                LOG.error("Target (enum) class must be an @Entity: {}", field.getType().getCanonicalName());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            Property enumReferenceAnnotatedProperty = persistentClass.getProperty(fieldName);
            persistentClass.getTable().createForeignKey(null,
                    Arrays.asList(enumReferenceAnnotatedProperty.getColumnIterator().next()),
                    targetPersistentClass.getEntityName());
        };

        Field[] declaredFields = persistentClass.getMappedClass().getDeclaredFields();
        of(declaredFields).filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(EnumReference.class)).forEach(
                createEnumFkConstraintForField);
    }

    private void createEnumInsertsAndDbColumns(PersistentClass persistentClass, Class<?> clazz,
            InFlightMetadataCollector metadata) {
        String tableName = persistentClass.getTable().getName();
        Enum<?>[] enumJavaConstants = clazz.asSubclass(Enum.class).getEnumConstants();

        ArrayList<String> insertCommandAccumulator = new ArrayList<String>(enumJavaConstants.length);

        Optional<Field> enumValueAnnotatedField = of(enumJavaConstants.getClass().getComponentType().getDeclaredFields())
                .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(EnumValue.class)).map(fieldWithEnumValue -> {
                    fieldWithEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
                    return fieldWithEnumValue;
                }).findAny(); // just none or one is supported

        if (enumValueAnnotatedField.isPresent()) {
            setMinimalFieldLengthOfExitingColumn(enumValueAnnotatedField.get(), enumJavaConstants, persistentClass);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < enumJavaConstants.length; i++) {
            Enum<?> it = enumJavaConstants[i];
            String constantEnumValue = enumValueAnnotatedField.map(v -> getInstanceValueOfEnumValueAnnotation(it, v))
                    .orElse(it.name());
            if (!enumValueAnnotatedField.isPresent()) {
                insertAdditionalColumn(persistentClass, metadata.getDatabase(), enumJavaConstants);
            }
            insertCommandAccumulator.add(createInsert(tableName, i, constantEnumValue));
        }

        InitCommand initCommand = new InitCommand(insertCommandAccumulator.toArray(new String[0]));
        persistentClass.getTable().addInitCommand(initCommand);
    }

    private void setMinimalFieldLengthOfExitingColumn(Field field, Enum<?>[] enumJavaConstants,
            PersistentClass persistentClass) {
        Property property = persistentClass.getProperty(field.getName());
        Column column = persistentClass.getTable().getColumn(Identifier.toIdentifier(property.getName()));
        Integer maxLengthOfEnums = maxLengthOfEnums(enumJavaConstants,
                e -> getInstanceValueOfEnumValueAnnotation(e, field));
        column.setLength(maxLengthOfEnums);
    }

    private String getInstanceValueOfEnumValueAnnotation(Enum<?> myEnum, Field enumValueAnnotatedField) {
        try {
            return enumValueAnnotatedField.get(myEnum).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Integer maxLengthOfEnums(Enum<?>[] enums, Function<Enum<?>, String> enumConstantValueExtractor) {
        return of(enums).map(it -> enumConstantValueExtractor.apply(it).length()).reduce(Math::max)
                .orElse(DEFAULT_VARCHAR_SIZE);
    };

    private void insertAdditionalColumn(PersistentClass persistentClass, Database database, Enum<?>[] enumJavaConstants) {
        Integer maxEnumStringLength = maxLengthOfEnums(enumJavaConstants, c -> c.name());
        Column column = new Column(DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME.render(database.getDialect()));
        String typeName = database.getDialect().getTypeName(Types.VARCHAR, maxEnumStringLength, 0, 0);
        column.setSqlType(typeName);
        persistentClass.getTable().addColumn(column);
    }

    private String createInsert(String tableName, int position, String dbEnumValue) {
        return ("insert into " + tableName + " values(" + position + ",\'" + dbEnumValue + "\')");
    }
}
```

Works for MySQL 5.7 and Hibernate 5.

It is not possible to JPA query `MyEnum` and its consistency between `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` and `getEnumConstants()` order is implicitly assumed.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO that does not have too much sense. The values of an `enum` are static and constant, while the values in a SQL table are dynamic. What if the DB does not contain exactly the values (no more, no less) for such enum?

EDIT: if you are forced to implement it, may something like this work?

```
public enum State{
    int primaryKey;
    NEW(0),OLD(1);
    public State(int pk) {
      primarykey = pk;
    }
}
```

And then join by primary key....

Comment: no doubt, that this is not a good solution. Yet, I have to implement it.

Comment: actually, your suggested proposal is wrong "Illegal modifier for the enum constructor; only private is permitted." - and with a private constructor, hibernate complains "No default constructor for entity"